# Http download stream in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can I read from mysql and write the same in http output stream.

So its like if send a request http://www.xyz.com/download/A
it should return me data for A from mysql through php.

The data is plain text.

Thanks
PS: I am new to php.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tutorial over at:

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: Yeah, why does this get voted down? (people should really own up to their voting down and comment, as recommended by SO)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just adapt it to your code by replacing the variables, table and column nammes with yours.

```
$sql = 'SELECT text FROM table WHERE id='.$id;

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die('SQL error');
$text = mysql_result($result);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $text;
```

Note, that you should not output any HTML or whitespace before sending the header, though.

Hope this helps.